# VB.Net sockets communicating with Android Socket

Tags: java, android, vb.net

I am trying to communicate between an android app and VB.net app using sockets. The VB app connects to socket ok but the the problem I am facing is that VB.net application only send the data to connected android socket when I call stream.Dispose.

Below is my code for both Android and VB.net

Android:

```
class Thread1 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Socket socket;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);

            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        txtviewIP.setText("Connected");
                    }
                });
                new Thread(new Thread2()).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class Thread2 implements Runnable {
        boolean bKeepRunning = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (bKeepRunning) {
            try {
                final String message = input.readLine();
                if (message != null) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Log.d("Message", "Command Received: " + message);
                            if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                                DoSomething();
                                bKeepRunning = false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            serverSocket.close();

            Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
            Thread1.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

VB.Net:

```
Dim clientSocket As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
Dim ipAddress As String
Dim port As String = "9877"
Dim serverStream As NetworkStream
Dim bConnected As Boolean = False

Public Function Connect() As Boolean

    Try
        clientSocket.Connect(ipAddress, port)

        serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
        bConnected = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        bConnected = False

    Finally

    End Try

    Connect = bConnected

End Function

Public Sub SendToServer(text As String)
    'Dim serverStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
    Dim outStream As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)
    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length)
    serverStream.Flush()

    'till this point no data is sent.
    'as soon as I call dispose or close data is sent 
    serverStream.Close() OR serverStream.Dispose()
    
    'Have also tried below code but this also do not work and behaves in the same way as above
    Dim stream As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(serverStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    stream.AutoFlush = True
    stream.Write(text)
    stream.Flush()
    'Data is sent as soon as the below line is executed
    Stream.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: It is unclear what the client sends. Please tell. Or better: show in your code.

Comment: `'Data is sent as soon as the below line is executed` Dont think so. The data was already send. But upon closing the client socket the data was received at server side.

Comment: @blackapps Client can send any string. And yes this is the problem that data is not received when it is sent. I don't want the socket to be connected and closed every time data needs to be sent. So need help in this regard. Same thing works just fine when I use sockets in java. But I need to implement this in VB.net

Comment: `Client can send any string. ` I believe so. But if the server does not receive it the string was not ok. So for the second time: show exactly which string you send. `So need help in this regard.` Indeed. Then give exact answers if asked.

Comment: Well that is not ok as it is no line. The server tries to read a line so you have to send a line. A line is a string ending on new line character `\n`. You can change to "Play:Video1.mp4\n" or just add the newline char when write().

Comment: ADD THE NEWLINE CHAR: `\n`. You are not even reacting on what i proposed!

Comment: @blackapps Thank you so much. It worked like a charm. All I had to add was Environment.NewLine. Again thank you so much.